# document.getElementById not working

Tags: javascript, client-side

I have 2 chekboxes on a page. There are wrapped in a table cell each within their own row. Doing a document.getElementById('chk1_FEAS~1005') returns the element but document.getElementById('chk5_STG2~1005') is null. For what reasons could this be happening? (I'm testing in IE 8).

```
<input id="chk1_FEAS~1005" value="JobStages###StageCode~JobCode###FEAS~1005" onclick="addRemoveRow(this.value,this.checked)" style="border-width:0px;padding:1px;margin:0px;height:14px;"  type="checkbox" />

<input id="chk5_STG2~1005" value="JobStages###StageCode~JobCode###STG2~1005" onclick="addRemoveRow(this.value,this.checked)" style="border-width:0px;padding:1px;margin:0px;height:14px;"  type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Providing an HTML document, with failing javascript in the HEAD tag, would help (create a trivial example from your real code, if need be).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your Id has invalid characters:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

More information [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html).

Comment: This is not the issue with the example, although you are correct that that is the recommendation.

Comment: cletus is right. The tilda causes javascript to ignore the remaining part of the Id (depending on browser), so it basically thinks both elements have the same ID: "chk1_FEAS", which is why one works, and one does not.

Comment: @IPX Ares: they don't both begin with chk1_FEAS though, so no.

Comment: and that is why I need more coffee... maybe it is just looking at the 1005? I know I have seen this before with invalid characters.

Comment: I'm tempted to think this is IE behaving funny. I can give those new id's so im happy to do that. Aside, any of you guys know how to get all the checkbox elements beginning with chk? $("input[type='checkbox'][id*=chk]") isn't working for me?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('hk5_STG2~1005')
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('chk5_STG2~1005')
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample it is a typo, the second item should be, `document.getElementById('chk5_STG2~1005')`

Also, I would recommend removing the ~ character as it is invalid for an id.

Comment: yep sorry it was a typo. document.getElementById('chk5_STG2~1005') is not working

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I have similar problems using `document.getElementById` on checkboxes in IE8. Try adding this tag to your head section :-

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

This will force IE8 into IE7 compatibility mode. It works for me as a workaround until I find-out what's really up.